# SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent

hi
i need to run a procedure every first day of month.
 And the procedure should automatically run at every month.
So with out using timer i have to use it. 
So i Think Better to go for **SqlServer agent** and shedule it. what should i need to configure this...i am using sqlserver 2008R2 version.
If i use sqlserver agent whether it will affect the performance of the server?.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need access to SQL Server Agent in order to do what you need to do.  This is done through `msdb` permissions:  [`SQLAgentUserRole`, `SQLAgentReaderRole`, and `SQLAgentOperatorRole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283).

You can create a job to adhere to your schedule, and then the job will execute whatever task it is that you need done.

As for the performance impact on the server, SQL Server Agent itself is negligable but whatever the job does will definitely be a consideration on when it is run, depending on how expensive the job is.  To give a better estimate on server impact, please tell us exactly what you need the job to do.

Comment: hi,thank u..
i need to credit the leave balance of employees every month.there are 750 employees..and i need to do this..\

Comment: @Sivajith so are you also asking how to write the query? I think that needs to be a separate question.

Comment: @Sivajith Aaron is right, are you looking for query help?

Comment: @Aaron.. no i am not asking for the query...i wrote it and executed but the problem is how to schedule it effectively..

Comment: Ok, so my answer answers your question then?

Comment: @shark gave the right answer, i guess you want to know how to create a job step by step, check this [link](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/step_by_step_guide_to_add_a_sql_job_in_sql_server_2005.aspx) or  [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712811/how-do-i-create-a-step-in-my-sql-server-agent-job-which-will-run-my-ssis-package)